# Binds C function using OpenCV to python with Swig

Tags: python, c, binding, opencv, swig

I use OpenCV and its Python wrappers on a daily basis to produce computer vision algorithms.

For several complex functions, we need to keep the C version which allows lower computation time and easier reuse.

In this way, I would like to bind C functions that use opencv structures like iplimage to use them in Python. Could you give me some tips on it? I
don't really know where to start actually.

Here is my structure which contains iplimages.

```
typedef struct{
    int nbBlobs;
    IplImage *labels;
    IplImage *contours;
}ccl_conf_t;
```

And here are the propotypes of my function:

```
int ccl_init(ccl_conf_t *conf, IplImage *frame);
void ccl_unInit(ccl_conf_t *conf);
int ccl_label(ccl_conf_t *conf, IplImage *frame, int option);
```

I would be grateful for any hint you could give me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Making a Python loadable module in C is quite easy. Start here: http://docs.python.org/c-api/

It's easy to take a small example from the Python source itself, extend to your own use. Look in the 'Modules' dir of the Python source.

Comment: Hummm. . . Thanks for the answer but it seems like your are talking about embedding Python into C code? My aim is just the opposite ! I got a C function, which should be used as Python function! Am I wrong?

Comment: Oops. I think I had the wrong link. I was looking for the "Extending Python with C/C++".  Take a look at http://docs.python.org/extending/extending.html#a-simple-example for a quick example of creating a C module that can be called from Python.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I'll try with that and let you know :). What kills me a bit is that what I want to do is already performed in python bindings for Opencv. I simply do not see how I could use it .